# Joint Distribution Multivariate Normal

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

Consider two random variables $X_1 , X_2$. Such that $X_1 \sim  N_r (µ_1
, Σ_{11})$ and $(X_2|X_1 = x_1) ∼ N_{p−r}(Ax_1 + b, \Omega))$, then
$(X_1,X_2) \sim N_p (\mu, \Sigma)$ where $\mu = (\mu_1, A\mu_1 + b)$

\begin{equation}
\Sigma  = \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{11}A\\ A\Sigma_{11} & \Omega + A\Sigma_{11}A'
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

I have tried considering the fat that $f(x_1,x_2) = f(x_2|x_1) f(x_1)$. However I do not know how to proceed then. Is there another way or should I proceed with the density functions?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you'd like help with? I don't see a question

Comment: I am trying to prove the result. Do you have any recommendations_

Comment: One option is to 'work forward' from the given $p(x_1)$ and $p(x_2 \mid x_1)$. As you've mentioned, $p(x_1, x_2) = p(x_2 \mid x_1) p(x_1)$. You can write out the joint density, and (after some algebraic manipulation), compare this to the given $p(x_1, x_2)$. Alternatively, you can 'work backward' from the given $p(x_1, x_2)$. Since it's Gaussian, you can use standard formulas to obtain the marginal and conditional distributions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)). Then, compare these to the given $p(x_1)$ and $p(x_2 \mid x_1)$

Comment: Also, since this appears to be a study exercise, please add the 'self-study' tag and have a look at its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)